# asp.net mvc displaying contents in view on condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a following view in my project where i have one dropdown and one textbox and submit button.I want to execute following scenario.

On click of submit only,I want to display the table contents.So if there is data,it will display data or else it will display "No records found".Is it possible?

My view is as follows:

```
 model mvclearn.Models.Employee
 @{
 ViewBag.Title = "menu";
 }
@{
 Layout = null;
 }

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .error {
    color: red;
   }
</style>
 <div class="container">
<div class="container"style="width:30%">
 @using (Html.BeginForm("save", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Service_Code, Model.ser_code, "--select--", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Service code" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Service_Code, "", new { @class = "error" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Service_Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Service Name" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Service_Name, "", new { @class = "error" })

<input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn-block" />
 }
```

```
 <table class="table">
 @{
   if (Model.data!=null && Model.data.Count() > 0)
   {
               <tr>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayName("Service_Code")
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayName("Service_Name")
                    </th>

                </tr>


           foreach (mvclearn.Models.Employee item in Model.data)
           {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Service_Code
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Service_Name

                </td>


            </tr>
       }
   }
   else
   {
       <p>No records found</p>
   }


       }


 </table>


 </div>
```

Comment: Of course. What is not working with your code?

Comment: instead of `p` tag, use `tr>td` so that it displays as a table row

Comment: put your opening and closing table tags inside your if condition.

Comment: Everything is working fine,but the problem is i am getting "No records found" when i run the application i.e without clicking the submit button only.

Comment: I think it is getting the model as empty so its going in else part.

Comment: you can use @if (Model.Empty) instead to check if model has value.

Comment: It happens because Model.data is empty when the page loads for first time. You need to handle that

Comment: @if(Model.Empty) is not working

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have done a nice job but the way you are dealing with the model seems to be incorrect.You cannot use `Model.data!= null` statement,instead,I suggest you to do something like this.Check whether the Model's attributes are null or not!

```
if (Model.EmployeeName!=null ){
   //your code here
}
```

Another possible  reason for your problem is the model returns null values so check whether the model's attributes has the values when it is in the view.

Hope it helped.

Comment: How to handle if Model.data is empty?Because after debugging i came to know  that Model.data  is empty.

Comment: There's nothing called model.data .. Either model or model.<some attribute in the model>. If your model is empty,then deal with that part first. :)

Comment: Does your model contain data when it is passed to the view?

Comment: data is the attribute in the model which contains the result fetched from the database to be displayed

Comment: The model is empty when entered value is not there in the database  and  i  had tried to found out how to handle the empty case but could not make it

Answer (score 0):

You Can Embed Table tag in the If condition like this ...

```
@if(Model.data!=null && Model.data.Count() > 0)
    {
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    }else{
         <p>There is no records</p>
    }
```

Comment: Paragraph tag will never appear inside the table tag

Comment: Not working.Actually on the page load,i am getting "There is no records".Actually i want to display something only after user clicks submit.